# Effects of anti-Rh(D) antibodies on the fetus

Tags: medications, immune-system, obstetrics, antibodies

Rh disease is caused by the irruption in the fetal circulation of anti-Rh(D) antibodies. This only happens when there has been a prior exposure of the mother to Rh+ RBC. To prevent Rh sensitization during pregnancy, anti-Rh(D) antibodies are typically administered during pregnancy.
The way anti-Rh(D) work in preventing Rh sensitization has been studied extensively: in short, it seems that they cover fetal RBC that have crossed the placenta, thereby preventing the mother's immune system from recognizing the Rh antigens. However, I have not been able to find a satisfying answer to the following question: **given that anti-Rh(D) use in the prevention of Rh disease are the same antibodies that *cause* Rh disease, and given in particular that they do cross the placenta, how does it come that they have no harmful effect on the fetus?**